# How to chat with yourself?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I haven't ever used the "Chat" features (which always seemed buggy and a bit forced), but now I'd like to create a chat room/session or otherwise send and receive chats to myself (between computers). 
Here's the setup details:

- Mathematica v12.0 is running
- $CloudConnected is True (with same wolfram cloud account email)
- Window menu > Chat settings > activated (with same username)

**What I've tried:**

I followed the steps in `workflow/CreateAChatRoom`:

```
<< ChatTools`
CreateChatRoom["selfchat", "Chatting with myself from multiple computers"]
```

But when I do `File > New > Chat Session...` and add "selfchat" as the contact, I get a $Failed message and some pinking:

[image]

This is easy to do with free chat clients like Slack and Rocketchat, but I'd like to know how to do it with MMA anyway.